# to make .ransack(params[:q]) operate on the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, ransack

Question model has_many Answers. Lines below count how many answers question has and order them according to the amount of answers in DESC order. So, most answered questions first.

```
@search = Question.find(:all,
                          joins: :answers,
                          select: ' "questions".*, count("answers".id) as answers_count', 
                          group: '"questions".id',
                          order: "answers_count DESC").ransack(params[:q])

@questions = @search.result
```

I also use ransack gem. For ransack to make search I need to add .ransack(params[:q]) to the @search array and call result method on this array. I though this could work, however it doesn't.

What could I use for ransack to start searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ransack first, then use it's result to chaining.

```
ransack_result = Question.ransack(params[:q]).result

@questions = ransack_result.find(:all,
                                 joins: :answers,
                                 select: ' "questions".*, count("answers".id) as answers_count', 
                                 group: '"questions".id',
                                 order: "answers_count DESC")
```